vscode popup for type is full of unwanted ampersands
i made this type that infers url pathname params from a string:
type Params<Pathname extends string> = string extends Pathname
  ? Record<string, string | undefined>
  : Pathname extends `${string}:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
  ? {
      [k in Param extends `${infer P}?` ? P : Param]: Param extends `${string}?`
        ? string | undefined
        : string;
    } & Params<`/${Rest}`>
  : Pathname extends `${string}:${infer Param}`
  ? {
      [k in Param extends `${infer P}?` ? P : Param]: Param extends `${string}?`
        ? string | undefined
        : string;
    }
  : {};

the problem is the vscode popup looks like this:
(parameter) params: {
    name: string;
} & {
    another: string | undefined;
} & {
    thing: string;
}

i tried adding some other Flatten types but then vscode just shows those in the popups too lmao
i want it to look like this in vscode:
(parameter) params: {
    name: string;
    another: string | undefined;
    thing: string;
}


consider raising an issue ticket on the typescript github repo. if you do, please add a link here to your ticket. but also check first if such a ticket has been raised before.

You could try the following utility:
type Simplify<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] : Simplify<T[K]>} extends infer A ? A : never;

Playground
